# How can i populate some textfield on selection of an option from the form:select having items as object list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a DTO with attributes id,name and text. I am generating a list of these DTO's and sending them into my JSP through model.addAttribute. In my jsp i am rendering a spring  list like this.

```
<form:select path="notificationsId" id="notificationsId" name="notificationsId">
     <form:options items="${templateList}" itemValue="notificationsId" itemLabel="notificationName" />
    </form:select>
```

Now i want to fill a textbox in my page with "notificationMessage", which is an attribute in my DTO. Of course i would want the text of the selected list item to be displayed. But the problem is that i could not find any way to do that. I cannot call some javascript on  tag to send different data to the function. The onclick method is of no use to me as i have different data for each list item. Can anyone please guide me how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You would use JavaScript.  I prefer jQuery, and would do something like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var dtoMap = new Array();
    <c:forEach items=${yourDtoArray}" var="dto">
      dtoMap['${yourKey}'] = '${yourVal}'
    </c:forEach>
    $('#notificationsId').change(function() {
      $('#notificationMessage').val($('notificationsId').val());
    });
  });
</script>
```

Give or take some fiddling to get the parts in line.